# scanf does not work

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation

im implementing a program that reads student id and names from stdin or file, and make them ordered by name and ordered by number. The funny thing is i cant understand why but scanf doesnt work. Here is my code while using scanf:

```
int n=0;
while(n<SIZE){
    scanf("%d %s\n",&std_array[n].id, std_array[n].name);
    n++;
}
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    printf("%d %s\n",std_array[i].id,std_array[i].name);
```

and here is my struct:

```
struct Student {
char *name;
int id;};
```

when i read from file and print them the out put is:

```
> 12586546 (null) 0 (null) 0 (null) 0 (null) 0 (null) 0 (null) 0 (null)
> 0 (null) 0 (null) 0 (null)
```

although file have some numbers and names like 21456764 john 45797654 fred etc. , its doesn't read successfully.

NOTE: i know the way we fix struct like you guys suggested but i must learn the way to do this with char pointer...

Comment: You should always test the result item count of `scanf`

Answer (score 2):

When doing this:

```
struct Student {
char *name; // This does not allocate memory
int id;};
```

Here, name *is a pointer, with no allocated memory, behaving like an uninitialized **literal** string*.

Trying to modify it creates **undefined behaviour**.

Replace with:

```
struct Student {
char name[50];
int id;};
```

or

```
struct Student {
char name[] = "Initial value gives maximum length. Do not write more!";
int id;};
```

Comment: ok i see the difference but if i use malloc, will that one solve the problem too ?

Comment: @yağızözbekevren By creating a mutable string, you will need to specify a limit, either by specifying a size,  or by initializing it.

Comment: `name is basically an uninitialized literal string.`...is it? IMHO, it's a pointer, right?

Comment: Detail: "Trying to modify it creates undefined behaviour."  Hmmm better said "Trying to modify what `name` points to is undefined behavior as it in not initialized.".  The whole idea of OP post is to properly modify the pointer `name`.

Answer (score 2):

This allocates memory to the pointer as needed. An intermediate variable is used to hold the string then only enough memory plus 1 for the terminating '\0' is allocated in the struct.

```
int n=0;
char name[100];//longest possible name
while(n<SIZE && ( scanf("%d%99s",&std_array[n].id, name) == 2)) {// successfully scanned two items
    std_array[n].name = malloc ( strlen ( name) + 1));
    if ( std_array[n].name == NULL) {
        printf ( "malloc failed\n");
        // break or return or exit(1) as appropriate
    }
    strcpy ( std_array[n].name, name);
    n++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d %s\n",std_array[i].id,std_array[i].name);
```

Eventually you will want to free the memory

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    free ( std_array[i].name);
}
```

Comment: that would help. gonna try now.

Comment: 1) Suggest `"%d%99s"` instead of `"%d %s\n"` : limit input to 99 and drop `'\n'` 2) Use `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`  (`n`, not `SIZE`)

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**

Allocate memory to `name` before using it. Otherwise, if used uninitialized, it does not point to any *valid* memory to read from or write into. You can use [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to allocate memory. Also, once done, don't forget to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) it once you're done using the memory.

**Point 2**

Remove the `\n` from `scanf()`.

Answer (score -1):

This is the corrected code

```
struct Student
{
char name[20];
int id;
};
struct Student std_array[SIZE];
int n=0;
while(n<SIZE)
{
    scanf("%d %s", &std_array[n].id, std_array[n].name);
    n++;
}
n=0;
while(n<SIZE)
{
    printf("%d %s\n", std_array[n].id, std_array[n].name);
    n++;
}
```

Hope this helps...,

Comment: Uhu i understand but this was my kinda homework. Lecturer told to make this struct with "char *name" and "int id". I have to learn to make it this way...

Comment: You still need to test the return value of `scanf` to make it *correct*

Answer (score -1):

as user3121023 told to me, it worked. fixed code is following:

```
struct Student {
char *name;
int id;
};

struct Student std_array[SIZE];
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b);
struct Student *order_by_number(struct Student *array);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

int n=0;
char name[100];
while(n<SIZE){
    scanf("%d %s\n",&std_array[n].id, name);
    std_array[n].name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    strcpy(std_array[n].name ,name);
    n++;
}
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    printf("%d %s\n",std_array[i].id,std_array[i].name);

order_by_number(std_array);

for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    printf("%d %s\n",std_array[i].id,std_array[i].name);
}
```

im done, ty guys for helping me. CASE CLOSED :)

Comment: `scanf("%d %s\n"` is weak. 1) return value not checked.  Check against `2`. 2) string size not limited `"%99s"` better than `"%s"` 3) `" "` not needed in `"%d %s\n"`.  4) `"\n"` in `"%d %s\n"` is certainly a problem with console I/O as it obliges `scanf()` to not return until additional non-white space or EOF is detected.  Best to drop it.  It does not simply scan 1 `'\n'`.